# How do I insert a record with a RECORD field in BigQuery using DML syntax?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this field which is a Record type with 3 sub-fields in a table (let's say table A). I want to copy to this table from another table (let's say table B) where these 3 fields are separate fields in BigQuery:

Table A:

```
env       Record
env.temp  INTEGER
env.ts    TIMESTAMP
env.desc  STRING
```

Table B:

```
env_temp  INTEGER
env_ts    TIMESTAMP
env_desc  STRING
```

I have no idea how to construct INSERT SQL statement in particular for this Record field (env):

```
INSERT table_A (env) SELECT ???? FROM table_B
```

Please enlighten me !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make a `STRUCT`, e.g.:

```
INSERT table_A (env)
SELECT STRUCT(env_temp AS temp, env_ts AS ts, env_desc AS desc) AS env
FROM table_B
```

Comment: FYI, if `env` was a repeated field, you would do as follow : `ARRAY[ STRUCT(...), STRUCT(...) ]`